# Custome rule of SonarQube Sever, will be synch to sonarlint

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have SonarqubeServer(`Version 5.6.3`), in which I have added two custom rules for java successfully, both are also visible in rule list.

Problem: I am also using Sonarlint for local eclipse issue. As usual their is sync issue for external plugins used by SonarqubeServer(PMD,FindBug,CHeckStyle). It is fine I have managed this.
So Now my question is that, will Sonarlint able to sync my newly added custom rules to SonarQubeServer?

if Yes then why I am not able to see those custom rule effect and reporting in eclipse classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about this, but i have activated Sonarlint support in pom.xml and it works for me. Here is the relevant entry, see  `<sonarLintSupported>`:

```
[...]
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.17</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <pluginClass>com.foobar.java.JavaRulesPlugin</pluginClass>
        <sonarLintSupported>true</sonarLintSupported>
        <sonarQubeMinVersion>5.6</sonarQubeMinVersion>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
[...]
```